# Obtain default attribute values from an Android theme at runtime?

Tags: android, styles, themes

I need to programmatically find out which drawable Android uses by default to render a `ProgressBar`. Since this is dependent on the theme being used, I tried something along the lines of:

```
    TypedArray progressBarAttrs = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            new int[] { android.R.attr.indeterminateDrawable });
    progressDrawableId = progressBarAttrs.getResourceId(0, -1);
```

But this always returns -1.

Is this because `android.R.attr.indeterminateDrawable` is not declared styleable or something? Is there any other way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

The following returns a drawable for me (trial and error, I certainly do not understand how obtainStyledAttributes exactly resolves):

```
 int[] attrs = new int[] { android.R.attr.indeterminateDrawable /* index 0 */};
 TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar, attrs);
 // ....
 ta.recycle();
```

However, when assigning that drawable to a progressBar:

```
 progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(ta.getDrawable(0));
```

The result does not look like the default ProgressBar indeterminate spinner. It is the Android spinner, but larger and thicker.

I have now idea why, but do notice that ProgressBar.java in Android, after retrieving the drawable resource, does something with it:

```
drawable = tileifyIndeterminate(drawable);
setIndeterminateDrawable(drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Happy to give you more help on Monday if you need it (Just heading out and noticed your question),

But check out Hackbods answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2130528/726954 and her link to the Sample project which will allow you pull styles resources back from a Theme.